# Why does image getting brighter when we decrease gamma?

Tags: image-processing

I've read about the power law (Gamma) Transformations so let's look to the equation: s = c*r^γ

Suppose that I have one pixel which has intensity of 37. If the gamma is 0.4 and c is 1, then the output intensity is `37^(0.4)` which is 4.2. Thus it's darker, not brighter. But then why does it look brighter in the example in my textbook?

Answer (score 1):

The gamma transformation applies to data in the range [0,1]. So, for your typical unsigned 8-bit integer image, you would have to scale it first to that range. The equation, including the scaling, then would be:

```
s = 255 * (r/255)^γ
```

Now you'd have, for `r = 37` and `γ = 0.4`: `s = 255 * (37/255)^0.4 = 117.8`. This is brighter.